# How to group in d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I'm trying to create a stacked, grouped, bar chart in d3 and I'm getting an issue where I try to add a rect that goes across the group, but it is generating the same rect for each group (so it duplicates for each group all the groups values).

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom').ticks(12));

    var loads = svg.selectAll(".load")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
      .attr("class", "load");

    loads.selectAll(".actexit")
      .data(data, keyFunction)
      .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "actexit")
    .attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.returnTime) - x(d.exitTime); })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.exitTime); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y0(`${d.truck}${d.order}`); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y0.rangeBand(); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return 'blue'; });

    loads.selectAll(".expexit")
      .data(data, keyFunction)
      .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "expexit")
    .attr("width", function(d) {  console.log(d); return '2px'; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.predictedExitTime); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y0(`${d.truck}${d.order}`); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y0.rangeBand(); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return 'red'; });
```

The code/demo can be found here: https://jsbin.com/heyuloz/2/edit?html,output

```
<svg width="960" height="500">
    <g transform="translate(40,20)">
        <g class="load">
            <rect class="actexit" width="56.94444444444457" x="626.3888888888888" y="21.42857142857143" height="192.85714285714286" fill="blue"></rect>
            <rect class="actexit" width="79.72222222222229" x="398.6111111111111" y="235.71428571428572" height="192.85714285714286" fill="blue"></rect>
            <rect class="expexit" width="2px" x="615" y="21.42857142857143" height="192.85714285714286" fill="red"></rect>
            <rect class="expexit" width="2px" x="410" y="235.71428571428572" height="192.85714285714286" fill="red"></rect>
        </g>
        <g class="load">
            <rect class="actexit" width="56.94444444444457" x="626.3888888888888" y="21.42857142857143" height="192.85714285714286" fill="blue"></rect>
            <rect class="actexit" width="79.72222222222229" x="398.6111111111111" y="235.71428571428572" height="192.85714285714286" fill="blue"></rect>
            <rect class="expexit" width="2px" x="615" y="21.42857142857143" height="192.85714285714286" fill="red"></rect>
            <rect class="expexit" width="2px" x="410" y="235.71428571428572" height="192.85714285714286" fill="red"></rect>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: green and blue bar should be stacked right .can you share screenshot , how it should look?

Comment: Thanks for commenting @NagaSaiA - I worked out why it was duplicating.  Yes, I have to get the green bars sorted next :)

Comment: no issues now right :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a case of me running it over the whole

```
.data(data)
```

rather than

```
.data(function(d) { return d; }).
```

The latter wasn't working for me because it is a single object and d3 was expecting an array - so I had to change it to:

```
.data(function(d) { return [d]; }
```